# Django How to use proxy models instead of parent

Tags: python, django, model

My code:

```
from django.db import models

class Animal(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

class Dog(Animal):
   class Meta:
     proxy = True

class Cat(Animal):
   class Meta:
     proxy = True
```

I want to do:

```
animals = Animal.objects.all()
```

but in animals, I should have only Dogs and Cats instances.

I need to cast an Animal object to a specific proxy model somehow.
How do I do that? in the **init** method?

Comment: `Cat.objects.all()` will generate all cats. Beware that a proxy models does *not* store anything specific in the database. It simply reuses the original table and generates items of a different type.

Comment: nit pick:  avoid overloading built-in names.  Try `animal_type` or `kind` instead of `type`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make something like:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   
  def __new__(cls, pk, type, *args, **kwargs):
        cons = None
        if cls is Animal:
            if type == 'cat':
                cons = Cat
            elif type == 'dog':
                cons = Dog
        if cons is None:
            return super().__new__(cls)
        return cons(pk, type, *args, **kwargs)
```

That being said, this is a bit of meta-programming that might not work ideal with all of Django (which is hard to test), and might not work well with other Django packages either.

Answer (score 1):

For pure proxy model inheritance, I like the solution presented here: https://schinckel.net/2013/06/13/django-proxy-model-state-machine/

For OP use-case, make 1 assumption / convention: that the name of the proxy class matches its `type` in some way.  With this convention, try:

```
class AnimalProxyMixin:
    """
    Mixin for Animal model that replaces instance class with a concrete subclass.
    """
    _subclass_map = None

    @classmethod
    def _get_subclass_map(cls):
        """Return a mapping from subclass name to subclass"""
        if cls._subclass_map is None:
            cls._subclass_map = dict([(sub.__name__, sub) for sub in cls.__subclasses__()])
        return cls._subclass_map

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._set_concrete_cls()

    def _set_concrete_cls(self):
        """Set the concrete class of this instance based on its type """
        cls_name = getattr(self, 'type', 'animal').title()
        self.__class__ = self._get_subclass_map().get(cls_name, self.__class__)


class Animal(AnimalProxyMixin, models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

class Dog(Animal):
   class Meta:
     proxy = True

class Cat(Animal):
   class Meta:
     proxy = True
```

And test:

```
assert all(a.__class__ in {Dog, Cat} for a in Animal.objects.all())
```

Caveat:  code works for direct sub-classes - recursively follow `__subclasses__` to traverse inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to `InheritanceManager` provided in django-utils to add polymorphism features to your model. https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

```
class Animal(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
  objects = InheritanceManager()

class Dog(Animal):
  pass

class Cat(Animal)
  pass

cats = Animal.objects.all().select_subclasses("cat")
```

Comment: OP is using proxy models.  This example uses multi-table inheritance.  `InheritanceManager` is great for that case, but I doubt it can work with proxy models, as there is no model-level info in the DB that it could use to know what kind of "Animal" a record is.  Only `type`, which has app-level semantics only.